# jQuery animation not working on page with update panel

Tags: asp.net, jquery, updatepanel

I've had a look around to see if this has been answered, and there are many similiar questions here but none that match the problem I'm having, so here goes.

I have a jQuery animation that runs on all pages. It works fine on all pages except those with a .NET Update Panel. The items that are animated are not part of the Update Panel at all, they have nothing to do with it.

When I click on the button that triggers the animation in question, it doesn't do anything. It gets called alright (a quick `alert("clicked!");` proved that) but it simply doesn't do anything. It sometimes looks as though it's trying, but failing, but there are no JavaScript errors reported.

From other similiar questions and answers here, people have suggested using jQuery's `.live()` and also the `PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest()` but none of these are valid here, as the items are outside of the Update Panel. (I've also given them a try, just in case!)

Has anyone else come across this issue before? Any help appreciated!

A quick edit...it appears that clicking the button that causes the animation is actually causing the update panel to reload, am not sure why as they're all set to conditional and have triggers associated with them.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed it myself. The jQuery click on the div that caused the animation was being propagated through to the UpdatePanel. Simply calling: event.stopPropagation() in the .click() function solved  the problem.

Comment: Haha, you can't accept your own answer :-) Oh apparently I can, in 2 days. I'll have forgotten by then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've fixed it myself. The jQuery click on the div that caused the animation was being propagated through to the UpdatePanel. Simply calling: event.stopPropagation() in the .click() function solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, if you are using events registered with .live() this will not work.

(Per the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)